# Split PDF by size - Size of the split PDF increasing

Tags: python

I have created a PDF Splitter using PyPDF2. It splits PDFs that are more than 20Mb in size into multiple smaller PDFs.

The logic I am using is to split all the Pages into single Page PDFs, find each one's size. Add the sizes till 20 Mb is reached and split.

The problem that I am facing is that there are certain pages in a PDF which take almost the same size as the original PDF. Although when I do page extraction manually the size is about 500Kb.

Not sure why the size increases. Please help me resolve these issues.

```
for i in range(pdf_reader.numPages):
    # New PDF with each page
    outputpdf = newpath + '\\' + pp.split('.pdf')[0] + 'page' + str(i+1) +'.pdf'

    #PDF Writer

    output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()

    #Writing each page to PDF Writer

    output.addPage(pdf_reader.getPage(i))

    #Write into the new PDF

    with open(outputpdf, "wb") as outputStream:

         output.write(outputStream)
```

Answer (score 1):

> The logic I am using is to split all the Pages into single Page PDFs, find each one's size. Add the sizes till 20 Mb is reached and split.

...

> Not sure why [...] the size increases.

---

## 1. Overhead

Any document format such as PDF is likely to contain a large amount of overhead material that is shared by many or all pages. One example would be a set of embedded fonts.

If you split a 100-page PDF into 100 separate PDF files, each of those will contain all the overheads needed for that page (more if your page-splitting library is not optimising this) - so you could end up with a set of PDFs that contain 100 copies of the embedded fonts.

The same could be true for other shared resources such as images and other more esoteric PDF resources.

You use functions that merge your separate pages back into, for example, a pair of single 50-page PDFs. If those functions cannot recognise the comment elements, the resulting PDF files will each now contain 50 copies of embedded fonts rather than one copy.

Another issue might be font-subsetting and re-merging. Or the absence of optimised re-merging.

---

## 2. Flattening etc

There are many ways to produce the same output on a printed page. Since your tool reads one PDF file and writes another, it is possible that it's PDF-writing options differ from that of the tool used to create the original file.

For example, Text can be stored in a PDF as text and associated fonts or as a flattened set of curved outlines. This can be done to avoid copyright issues when using commercially licensed typefaces. Outlines might take more space because each letter "a" in the text is represented as a repeat of the same curves rather than as a reference to a single coommon glyph in an embedded font or in a standard external font.

There are probably many other similar differences that are possible in other parts or types of PDF content.

---

## 3. Analysis

I'm not saying this is what is happening, just that this sort of thing is a possibility. You might be able to discover more by using some tool that analyses the content of a PDF file or by using a different approach or tool.

---

Searching for [analyse PDF file](https://www.google.com/search?q=analyse+pdf+file) returns options such as

- http://pdf-analyser.edpsciences.org/
- https://github.com/bthorben/pdf-analyser
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3549541/best-tool-for-inspecting-pdf-files